# How do you prevent interruptions in a C++ function?

Tags: c++, interrupt, keyboardinterrupt

I'm running a long computation in Linux, and every now and then I save partial results. I'd like to prevent interruptions in the function that saves partial results: for example, if a user presses CTRL-C, I want the function to finish and then the program to stop running).

For example, in the following code, I want that each "Saving..." is followed by a "Done".

```
#include <iostream>

void save_result(int i) {
  disable_interruptions();  // WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?

  std::cout << "Saving...";
  /* open some files, edit them depending on i, etc. */
  std::cout << "Done\n";

  enable_interruptions();   // WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?
}

int main() {
  while(true) {
    int i = 1;  /* some long computation */
    save_result(i);
  }
}
```

What I tried:

- Use some properties of file atomicity. Unfortunately, I have to change many files in various places, and I cannot do all the updates at the same time.
- Copy the files, edit the copy, move back atomically to the original place. The files are huge, and it will take too much time.

Comment: This is operating system dependent. Since the question did not mention which operating system no further info can be given.

Comment: You didn't specify your operating system. If it is POSIX-compatible (like Linux), you want to install a [temporary signal handler](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) to ignore `SIGINT`

Comment: `#pragma DI` and `#pragma EI` - this is something you made up, right?

Comment: For Windows (only), see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function

Comment: Signal handlers are **very constrained** as to what they are allowed to do.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ critical section" and add your operating system.  In the embedded systems world, it's called a *critical section*.

Comment: Updated the question to include the operating system and removed the `#pragma DI` solution (it came from https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka003774/latest/ plus some extra research, but probably I'm misinterpreting the document).

Comment: You can do this the hard way or the easy way.  Recommending easy: save the file with a temporary name, rename it afterwards.

Comment: As explained in the question, the files are very large and I want to edit only a small part: I cannot copy the whole files every time. I think I have to go for the hard way.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews a critical section won’t protect against a signal, since signal handler’s generally don’t (in fact can’t) acquire a lock on a critical section.

Comment: you can keep a log of changes to apply sort of like a file system does.   make sure the log is idempotent and can be applied repeatedly and then don't clear the log entry until you know it's been successfully applied.  This is filesystem kind of stuff and it's presumably not easy.

Comment: Rather than disabling interrupts, add an interrupt handler that sets a flag, periodically check that flag in relevant functions (e.g. your log function), and terminate normally when the flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching the signal and re-raising it, the ideal solution is actually to *mask out* the signal, which will cause the kernel to queue it up. Then, as soon as you unmask, the signal will be delivered. Here's an example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Masking out all signals\n";
    sigset_t oldset, newset;
    sigfillset(&newset);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &newset, &oldset) < 0) {
        perror("sigprocmask");
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::cout << "Unmasking..." << std::endl;
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, NULL);
}
```

In a multithreaded program, use `pthread_sigmask`. When a signal is directed at the process as a whole (as is the case with a `SIGINT` generated by the terminal, for example) it can be handled by one of the threads that does not have that signal masked out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Homer512 for pointing me in the right direction. We can capture the actions that stop the program using a signal handler, and re-raise the signal after we finished our update. Code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

// The signal that we received.
// We use a global variable for simplicity, in reality it's better
// to wrap it in a class. We use an atomic in case multiple signals
// come at the same time (not sure if it's really needed). 
std::atomic_int received_signal = NSIG;

void SignalHandler(int signal) {
  received_signal = signal;
}

void save_result(int i) {
  // From now on, instead of killing the program, these actions
  // will trigger our signal handler.
  signal(SIGINT, SignalHandler);   // CTRL-C
  signal(SIGHUP, SignalHandler);   // Close terminal
  signal(SIGQUIT, SignalHandler);  // CTRL-/

  std::cout << "Saving...";
  /* open some files, edit them depending on i, etc. */
  std::cout << "Done\n";

  // Reset these actions to default behavior.
  signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
  signal(SIGHUP, SIG_DFL);
  signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);

  if (received_signal != NSIG) {
    raise(received_signal);
  }
}
```

Other links:

- [Explanation of signal handlers](https://linuxhint.com/signal_handlers_c_programming_language/).
- [Control Handlers in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function) (from Paul Sander's comment, you can use it to adapt the solution to Windows).

Comment: This stops SOME signals but doesn't guarantee your file is changed atomically or that it's in any type of consistent state.  And why would you re-raise the last signal received but not the other signals that may have come in?  Either these things are important to do right (which this doesn't) or it's not important and this is just unneeded complexity.   The chances that the problem is so specific that this is the right solution is likely vanishingly small.

Comment: Good points. For atomicity, I can add a flag on the file that says if it's in a consistent state, just to make sure I at least catch the remaining problems (in my case, a CTRL-C is much more common than, say, the computer turning off unexpectedly). Do you have suggestions on how to stop all/more signals? For re-raising, yes, a better logic might help, in this case I wanted just the program to stop, and either of these signals does it.

Comment: if your app can recover from corrupted files, I suggest you just have it do that all the time.   Having a "backup code path" usually means you don't have a backup code path (that works).   When you need it that's when you'll find out it's broken.   Just use the most resilient process all the time.